# UIActivityIndicatorView inside UIButton

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uibutton, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a couple of programmatically generated UIButtons (custom, 200 by 200, white background) where i wanted to put a UIActivityIndicatorView inside. I tried it with the following code:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *playlistImageLoader = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
playlistImageLoader.center = CGPointMake(100, 100);
playlistImageLoader.hidesWhenStopped = YES;

[playlistImage addSubview:playlistImageLoader];
[mainScrollView addSubview:playlistImage];

[playlistImageLoader startAnimating];
```

But it doesn't show up? Have any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: I think your playlistImageLoader can work well, maybe playlistImageLoader center.x center.y is too high, or your playlistImage mainScrollView's problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>You didn't set the indicator frame, set it and it will be alright to have it as a button subview.</s>

Try to use `UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray` - `UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite` is invisible on the white background.

Comment: that is how UIActivityIndicatorView works, it needn't set it's frame

Comment: @DJean you are right, i'm wrong - that's not needed in this case. Updated the answer

Comment: Haha wauw perfect, how could i have made this mistake!

Comment: @Terwanerik just like any of us did i believe because it `is` visible at iOs prior 4.0 release.