# Adding UIActivityIndicatorView in a UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiactivityindicatorview

I have read various posts here about adding a UIActivtyIndicatorView in a UIButton but none of which have helped me so far.

I have a tableview with cells that each have button in them what say "go". 
When a user clicks a button, I want the button to display a UIActivtyIndicatorView until all of the background stuff is done. Here I am using some parse methods to save user info in the background.

I have a method

```
- (void)going:(UIButton *)button {

    NSLog(@"going button pressed");

    //Added this code
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:button.bounds];
    [button addSubview:activity];
    [activity startAnimating];

    if ([button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Go"]) { // Select
     ....
     // Just code changing user info

        [PFObject saveAllInBackground:save block:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

            if (success) {

                //Do more stuff so save user info in background
            }
        }];
    }
    else { // Deselect

        //More stuff
            if (success) {

                //Toggle button
                [defaults setObject:@"" forKey:@"currentBarID"];
                [defaults synchronize];
                selectedGoingToButton = nil;
                [self deselectGoingButton:button];
                [self reloadData];
            }
        }];
    }
}
- (void)selectGoingButton:(UIButton *)button {



    NSLog(@"GoingButtonselected");
    [button setTitle:@"Going" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.layer.borderColor = neonBlue.CGColor;
    [button setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

As you can see these two methods are where I toggle the button from a plain color to a highlighted color, but before the button highlights I want that UIActivityIndicatorView to display.

Currently it does not show, and the button just toggles color without displaying the ActivtyIndicator.

Any help is appreciated. thank you!

EDIT: Changed the UIActivityView init line so that I now pass in the button.bounds property.

ActivtyIndicatorView is now displaying, but now my issue is that the reload circle displays under the "GO" button title, and then stops when the title changes. I want it so that the button title disappears when the ActivityIndicator is showing. Any suggestions?

Comment: The activity view's frame needs to be relative to the button. Is your button really more than 300 points wide?

Comment: I see, how can I get the frame from the button passed in the parameter? @rmaddy

Comment: Use the `bounds` property.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have made an edit. Now I just have another issue I am trying to work out. @rmaddy

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIActivityIndicatorView inside UIButton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360259/uiactivityindicatorview-inside-uibutton)

Comment: Please use a little bit more research prior posting: changing the title of a button to `@" "` is all you need to make a title disappear. The question becomes off topic and may lose its interest.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)selectGoingButton:(UIButton *)button 
{

    activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 25, 50, 50)];
    activityIndicator.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [activityIndicator setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [yourview addSubview:activityIndicator];


    NSLog(@"GoingButtonselected");
   [button setTitle:@"Going" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.layer.borderColor = neonBlue.CGColor;
   [button setNeedsDisplay];
}







- (void)going:(UIButton *)button 
{

    NSLog(@"going button pressed");

    //Added this code
//UIActivityIndicatorView *activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:button.bounds];
//[button addSubview:activity];
//[activity startAnimating];

   if ([button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Go"]) { // Select
   ....
   // Just code changing user info

       [PFObject saveAllInBackground:save block:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

           if (success) {

               //Do more stuff so save user info in background
           }
       }];
   }
   else { // Deselect

       //More stuff
           if (success) {

               //Toggle button
               [defaults setObject:@"" forKey:@"currentBarID"];
               [defaults synchronize];
               selectedGoingToButton = nil;
               [self deselectGoingButton:button];
               [self reloadData];
           }
       }];
   }

[activityIndicator stopAnimating];
[activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
activityIndicator = nil;
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you, but this solution still does not put the activityIndicator above the stop view of the button. For some reason I still see the title of the button, and the indicator just hovers over it. The indicator does not cover the title layer.

Comment: I think you need to make your indicator bigger? right? I have just given my size(50,50) change this if you wanna bigger one.

Answer (score 1):

Why go through so much trouble and attempt to embed `UIActivityIndicatorView` inside another Cocoa view, being a `UIButton`, a `UITextView`, or else.

Why not just put your `UIActivityIndicatorView` above like so? This is guaranteed to work.

```
UIActivityIndicatorView * spin = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
    initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
spin.center = myButton.center;
[myButton.superview insertSubview:spin aboveSubview:myButton];
[spin startAnimating];
```

Comment: I still have the problem with this implementation where the indicator does not cover up the button below it. The button still displays the "GO" on it and just has the spinning happening. I can see bot the "GO" and the spinning of the indicator and I just want to be able to see the spinner.

Comment: Change the button transparency

Comment: @milesper: thinking about forward compatibility, Autolayout constraints and such, I would put both the `UIButton` and the `UIActivityIndicatorView` in a common superview, over which I will apply both layout and alpha.